# Matlab - filter out identical cell entries

Tags: string, matlab, compare

My matrix is a 10000 x 2 one. Looks like this:

> Ann Beth
>
> Bob Pete
>
> Sam Sam
>
> Jen Ted
>
> ...

There are many lines with identical names in both columns (like Sam). I need just rows with different names. I thought of a for-loop with ismember/string compare but this is very slow and there are some matrixes like this.
Other option that is also slow is to unique the first column and run a for loop with find the unique values and delete every time the values of find are identical. However this is slow as well. Please help to optimize.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [strcmp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) to get a logical array of indices corresponding to identical rows, i.e. compare 1st column with 2nd and remove rows corresponding to indices of 1.

```
Example:

C = {'Ann' 'Beth';

'Bob' 'Pete';

'Sam' 'Sam';

'Jen' 'Ted'};

idx = strcmp(C(:,1),C(:,2))
```

Here `idx` looks like this:

```
idx =

     0
     0
     1
     0
```

Hence the 3rd row contains identical names. Now remove those:

```
C(idx,:) = [];

C = 

    'Ann'    'Beth'
    'Bob'    'Pete'
    'Jen'    'Ted'
```